# Plotly-Dash: Aggregate inputs and outputs to reflect complex python objects

Tags: python, plotly-dash

How can I use the aggregate of several html elements to signify an object.

For example, say I had a python object named TaggedCoordinates, whose instances had attributes t.x, t.y, and t.tag. If I wanted to display such an instance in a page, or have a form to ask the user to input one, I’d use two numerical elements for x and y, and a string element for tag. In a call back, I’d have something like

```py
@callback(..., [...], [State(x_id), State(y_id), State(tag_id)])
def store_tagged_coordinate(x, y, tag):
    …
```

But I’d much rather have something like:

```py
@callback(..., [...], [State(tag_coord_id)])
def store_tagged_coordinate(tag_coord):
    …
```

How can I achieve something like that?
I could group the html elements in a div with a specific id (say `tag_coord_id`), but how would I then make dash understand that I want to get a "struct" or dict of it's constituents as a single python `tag_coord` variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution (but will wait to see if there's a better one out there).

Write a converter function that will convert a div that groups the object-relevant html elements, then use it in the callback function. Like so:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass
class TaggedCoord:
    x: float
    y: float
    tag: str

def obj_for_div(d):
    return TaggedCoord(*[c.value for c in d.children])
```

Then if you have, in your layout, something like:

```py
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
d = html.Div(children=[dcc.Input(id='x', value=0, type='number'), 
                       dcc.Input(id='y', value=0, type='number'), 
                       dcc.Input(id='tag', value='', type='text')],
      id='tagged_coord')
```

```py
@callback(..., [...], [State(tag_coord_id)])
def store_tagged_coordinate(..., tag_coord):
    tag_coord = obj_for_div(tag_coord)
    ...
```

See that

```py
>>> obj_for_div(d)
TaggedCoord(x=0, y=0, tag='')
```